# Help understanding this pulsing LED circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, circuit-analysis

I started learning about op amps, and I came by this circuit and thought I should be able to understand it. What is tripping me up is how is it pulsing or varying with time? The source is supposedly a 9v battery, so the time dependence doesn't come from there. I thought maybe it comes from the capacitors, but I can only come up with is that the capacitors act like a short circuit at time zero and act like an open circuit at time infinity. I know they have to do with how long the pulses are but I don't know how in a technical sense. Like how are they charging and discharging? Maybe the capacitors are causing a flip between positive and negative feedback?

[image]

Comment: ["Comparator Based Relaxation Oscillator"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator)

Comment: That’s a very badly designed relaxation oscillator. Placing that much load to an op-amp just to put a pole in the right place smells of just trial and error to me. And BTW. One of those 2.2mf capacitors is going to fail sooner rather than later.

Comment: The two 2.2 mF caps look like a mistake to me.  Other than causing heating in the opamp output stage and decreasing battery life, they serve no purpose. I suppose it could have something to do with forming a linear ramp when the opamp output stage is in current limiting, but - what - ???

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this circuit is a relaxation oscillator built using an op-amp or comparator and relying on hysteresis to oscillate.

If you ignore the two 2.2mF capacitors, the circuit would still work.

In terms of the rest of the circuit, the three 10k resistors connected to the "+" input of the op-amp act firstly to form a bias around mid supply as you have only a single supply rail, and secondly to add some hysteresis to the circuit. When the output changes, the bias voltage will also change as a result.

The magic happens then with the interaction of this hysteresis with the 10k resistor (I will call **R1**) and 100uF capacitor (I will call **C1**) combination. R1 and C1 act as an R-C circuit, which in couple with the hysteresis provides the oscillation.

### At t=0

Lets say C1 is discharged so the "-" terminal is at 0V, and the "+" terminal is biased to either ~3V or ~6V depending on the output voltage. We can see in this condition that we have positive feedback forcing the output high (the "+" terminal is way above the "-" terminal). With the output high, our "+" terminal is therefore biased to 6V.

### At t=RC

Over the last RC time period, C1 has been slowly charging up through R1. After one RC time constant the voltage across C1 and hence at the "-" terminal is charged to about 6V (actually it takes a little bit longer, but I'm going to ignore that for simplicity).

When this condition is reached, the "-" terminal becomes higher than the "+" terminal. This causes the output to start swinging down towards 0. Due to the feedback resistor in the bias circuit, this also causes the bias voltage to begin dropping as well. This positive feedback causes the output to slam down to 0V, and the bias voltage to drop to 3V. C1 starts to discharge

### At t=2RC

C1 has been discharging through R1 because the output is low, and has now discharged to ~3V. When this happens the voltage at the "-" terminal is now below the voltage at the "+" terminal.

This causes the output to start swinging down towards 9V. Due to the feedback resistor in the bias circuit, this also causes the bias voltage to begin rising as well. This positive feedback causes the output to slam up to 9V, and the bias voltage to rise back to 6V. C1 starts charging again.

---

The process then continues forming the required oscillation.

I believe the two 2.2mF capacitors are added to give the oscillator a kick to start running, potentially to overcome the pull-down effect of the LEDs. However I could be wrong about that.

Comment: I suggest that the 2.2mF caps are incorrectly shown in the schematic.  The caps are in anti-parallel connection (polarities reversed).  The cap terminals connected to +9V will **always** be more positive than the terminals connected to the op-amp output.  Thus, one cap will always be reversed biased--not an acceptable design.

Comment: Yeah there's more wrong with those capacitors, generally connecting a capacitor from a supply line to op-amp output is asking for trouble. I wonder what the designer was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 2 capacitors from VDD to opamp output.

There is no startup problem with this circuit. This is a standard dual-loop opamp triangle-wave + square-wave oscillator; the "triangle wave" is on (-) input to opamp; the square-wave is the opamp output.

Answer (score 0):

I do not disagree with Tom's answer. This might help, (Dave's law): In a closed loop op-amp circuit (like yours) the output of the op-amp will do whatever it needs to do to (try) to make the (-) input equal to the (+) input. I put "try" in parenthesis because a pulsing circuit will never stabilize. In your circuit the output is alternately switching from high to low (rail to rail). In conventional servo loops, the op-amp output will change in analog fashion in response to voltages appearing at the two inputs.

Comment: If that were the case, there would be no need to distinguish between the + and - inputs.